# Serialize, only the answer, not whole sentence

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a problem. I have a form, where you can fill in all your details. It updates automatically, but serialize gives me "bar=xxx" and not only xxx how can it display only xxx. I hope that someone could help me!
This is my code:

```js
$(function() {
    var update = function() {
        $('#serializearray').text(        
            JSON.stringify($('#hello').serializeArray())
        );
        $('#serialize').text(        
            JSON.stringify($('#hello').serialize())
        );
    };
    update();
    $('form').change(update);
})
```

```css
div {
    margin-top: 27px;
}
#serializearray, #serialize {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #111;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 9px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <input id='hello' name="bar" value="xxx" />
</form>

<div>$('form').serializeArray():</div>
<div id=serializearray>asfdg</div>

<div>$('form').serialize():</div>
<div id=serialize>asfdg</div>
```

Comment: `$('#hello').val()`...

Comment: PHP serialize is not jQuery serialize

Answer (score 0):

You looking for something that returns all the form values like this maybe:

```
   var update = function() {
        $('#serializearray').text(        
            $.map($('form').serializeArray(),function(a) {
                return a.value;
            }).join(", ")
        );
    };
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldneuo4h/)